# How to install extensions offline?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to install Go language extension and few others to my Visual Studio Code. However I don't have internet connection on this machine. How can I install extensions offline with Visual Studio Code? I don't see and download links for extensions on the site, and I couldn't find any documentaion on how to get and install extensions offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install VSCode extensions offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071388/how-to-install-vscode-extensions-offline)

Comment: you can read this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071388/how-to-install-vscode-extensions-offline