# where to download powershell extension file for vscode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have `vscode` running on windows 10, and it keeps telling me to install the 'Powershell' extension. 
But when I click on the Install button, I get an error `connect EACCES 191.238.172.191:443`.

So I was just going to download it and install it directly. But I can't find a link to the file anywhere.

I've tried searching for it on the marketplace, but there is so many, and no indication of which one is the recommended one.

Can anyone tell me where to go to download the file?

I even tried the direct URL of `https://Microsoft.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Microsoft/extension/PowerShell/0.9.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage` But that doesn't work either.

---

UPDATE
OK, found it. The link is:
https://ms-vscode.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-vscode/extension/PowerShell/0.9.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackag

The publisher should be `ms-vscode`. Then after downloading, remove the work package from the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions are at this site: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode.

To install, see [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/install-extension), which contains this:

> Install from a VSIX You can manually install an VS Code extension
>   packaged in a .vsix file. Simply install using the VS Code
>   --install-extension command line switch providing the path to the .vsix file.

```
code --install-extension myextension.vsix
```

Also, see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7706) on github, re: connect EACCES. Are you behind a proxy (e.g. at work)? If so, have you added proxy settings to your user settings?

```
"http.proxy": "",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

Try looking at/following all the steps listed in that link.

Comment: cheers. Getting IT to change the Proxy server will take forever unfortunately, if at all. The `--install-extension` option would be great, except that I need to get the `vsix` file first, and that's what I'm currently trying to do. Where can I download that file from? I looked at the marketplace but there doesn't appear to be 'download vsix file here' button.

Comment: You don't need to get IT to change the proxy server, you need to add in the proxy server address into VS Code settings/preferences.

Comment: cheers, but as before, getting the necessary details from IT requires a lot of time and effort explaining what I need and why. Surely there is a way to download the file directly? I only need this one extension.

Comment: Grab it from Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

Comment: No, it just has `automatically detect settings` selected.

Comment: See this SO answer on how to find the url for a package, download & install manually: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38866913/1368849

Comment: OK cheers, It turns out the publisher should be `ms-vscode` not `Microsoft`