# VS Code change link for marketplace

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code, artifactory, vscode-extensions, marketplace

I have before worked with Python extensions and configured PIP to point to our artifactory in my company, now I would like to do the same with VS Code.

I would like to be able to change the path of where VS Code downloads its extensions, to our own artifactory. 
We want to control what users have which extensions, and don't want them to be able to download freely.

Can anyone please help me to which file or configuration I can make to point it to another site?

Comment: I have found out you can open VSCode\resources\app\product.json and delete the URL from "serviceUrl". This will stop users from downloading extensions from the marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. There is already an issue concerning this feature https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21839 .

You can however disable the Gallery as mentioned by Thally by removing the "extensionsGallery" part from `VSCode\resources\app\product.json`.

And offer the vsix you want your users to have via any differnt path for selfservice or even just preinstall them under `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`.

VSIX can be downloaded from the store for offline use as Mentioned by [t3chb0t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235671/t3chb0t) in his answer to [how-to-install-vscode-extensions-offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866913/4955637)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still running into this, an updated answer is to use https://github.com/LOLINTERNETZ/vscodeoffline

So far it has worked well for us in a completely offline environment. The only gotcha that we have run into is that some extensions attempt to reach out and download additional things from github or elsewhere when first run which does not work if you are offline like in my situation. However, if you are online and simply want to control which extensions are available, I think this project will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, by adding a `product.json` file to their user directory or setting `env vars`, **your coworkers will be able to change the marketplace again**: https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/pull/674