# How to get Visual Studio Extensions from internal corporate network?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We're trying to use Visual Studio Code within an internal, corporate network so we don't have access to the Visual Studio Extension Marketplace. Has anyone had a similar issue and found a way to either mirror the marketplace on their internal network or been able to download the extensions locally to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download from marketplace website and install in Visual Studio Code, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866913/4772880