# How to install python language server for vscode python extention offline

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python, python-language-server

I'm working in a Linux offline environment for security reasons. We have a channel to get scanned files to the system so I can install python extension but can not install the python language server because vscode can not connect to the internet directly.

Is there a way to download an installation files so I can install it offline?

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install VSCode extensions offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071388/how-to-install-vscode-extensions-offline)

Comment: I installed python extension using this method. But the extension itself need to download the python launage server to use the faster (compare to jedi) autocomplete feature.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to install extension on some other system which would help you download the resources required for autocomplete feature and then copy the extensions folder to your target system. See [this](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/) to find your extensions folder.

Comment: Thank you @CodeIt I'm hoping to avoid using another machine as it is very hard to request (tons of paperworks) and take forever to get the approval just to use it. But sounds like this is the only way :/

Answer (score 0):

Offline installs are not officially supported, but [the code that handles the download and extraction](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/src/client/activation/languageServer/downloader.ts) is publicly available, so you can try to reverse-engineer what the extension is doing. But regardless you will still need to download the language server somewhere to get it on to the computer to unpack it.

Comment: Thank you, Brett. I'll give it a try :)