# How to install previous version of Python extension for VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to install previous version of Python extension for VSCode (ms-python.python) to troubleshoot something, but when I am trying to use context menu with "Install another version..." I just have an error "server returned 404"

Answer (score 14):

You need to install it from a `.vsix` file. You can find them [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/releases).
Download the `.vsix` file of the version you want. You may have to click `assets` to see them.
Then open VSCode, go to `extensions` -> click on the three dots -> `install from vsix` and select your file.
To install the `.vsix` you can also use the command

```sh
code --install-extension ms-python-release.vsix
```

[image: How to install from vsix]

sources :
- [How can I install Visual Studio Code extensions offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071388/how-can-i-install-visual-studio-code-extensions-offline)
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix

Comment: Thanks! I am pleasantly surprised by how straightforward that was!

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Unfortunately your "download" link only points to release history with source code download. Any hint where I find the vsix file of an older version?

Comment: @GeorgW. You can find some .vsix files for the extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) but I'm not sure where to find them for older versions since they are no longer in the github releases. Rahul Chavan's answer might help you.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/20184): You can modify the URI template `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-python/vsextensions/python/{version}/vspackage` by replacing `{version}` with the version you want to download, e.g. `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-python/vsextensions/python/2022.16.1/vspackage` for 2022.16.1.

Comment: That is true. The version history can be found on this page https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases this way you know which version to chose from.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using "Install Another Version" option available with VS Code extension  store.

1. Go to extensions.
2. Click on Gear Icon for the installed extension
3. Click on Install Another Version
4. And select the version you wish to install
   [image: Select Version Option]

Comment: This option isn't available on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The 404 issue is a [bug in the VS Code marketplace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99699). They are actively working to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UI now supports "Install another version" option in VS Code version 1.76.0.

[VS Code Extensions - Install another Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nusNp.png)