# How can I download a VS Code extension with multiple platforms via direct download URL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, curl

Following the [common questions](https://vscode-docs1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/extension-gallery/#common-questions) sections of the VS Code Extension Marketplace [docs](https://vscode-docs1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/extension-gallery/), I can download a VS Code extension such as [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) or [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) directly from its  direct download URL in the form

```
http://${publisher}.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/${publisher}/extension/${extension name}/${version}/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage
```

by directly loading the file in browser to download, via cURL, or this convient python [script](https://gist.github.com/taylor-jones/78d4db0163bb0ae94131f58c75f425fe).

cURL example with latest python VS Code extension:

```
curl https://ms-python.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-python/extension/python/latest/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage -o ms-python.python.vsix
```

cURL example ESLint extension version 2.4.0:

```
curl http://dbaeumer.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/dbaeumer/extension/vscode-eslint/2.4.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage -o vscode-eslint.vsix
```

The VS Code C++ [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), on the other hand, has many platforms (Windows ia32, Alpine Linux 64 bit, Alpine Linux ARM64, macOS Intel, Linux x64, Linux ARM32, Linux ARM64, macOS Apple Silicon, Windows ARM, Windows x64), and I don't see an explicit means to choose one in the URL form mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to [the C++ extension page you linked](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) and just clicked download on one and looked at my browser's devtools' network tab. I chose "Windows ia32", and the download url was `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode/vsextensions/cpptools/1.15.3/vspackage?targetPlatform=win32-ia32`. Of interest is the query part of the URL: `?targetPlatform=win32-ia32`. If you just search "targetPlatform" in the HTML source, you'll find there's a `<script>` tag containing a JSON object where one of the fields is:

```json
"TargetPlatforms": {
  "win32-x64": "Windows x64",
  "win32-ia32": "Windows ia32",
  "win32-arm64": "Windows ARM",
  "linux-x64": "Linux x64",
  "linux-arm64": "Linux ARM64",
  "linux-armhf": "Linux ARM32",
  "darwin-x64": "macOS Intel",
  "darwin-arm64": "macOS Apple Silicon",
  "alpine-x64": "Alpine Linux 64 bit",
  "web": "Web",
  "alpine-arm64": "Alpine Linux ARM64"
}
```

The keys in that object are the parts you put in the `targetPlatform` query parameter value, and the values in that object are text for display purposes (you don't care about them for what you're doing here).

There's also a `Versions` field that you might find interesting (looks like this):

```json
"Versions": [
  {
    "version": "1.15.3",
    "lastUpdated": "Tue, 25 Apr 2023 01:57:52 GMT",
    "targetPlatform": "win32-ia32"
  },
```