# Do VSIX files for extension packs include the VSIX files of the packed extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I seems like some VSIX files install more than one extension.
For instance,

- Remote-SSH by Microsoft also installs Remote-SSH-Edit and Remote-Explorer.
- Python also install Pylance
- updating Pylance (or installing flake8) also installs a bunch of Juptyer stuff.

The target machine will not have internet access.

Are the extra extensions "baked" into the original VSIX file? or do I need to go grab those extensions' VSIX files also?

(I ran into a problem where a extension installed an older version of another extension and I couldn't find the download for the extra extensions version)

Comment: This might help in a way: [petah's answer on "How can I install Visual Studio Code extensions offline?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678874/4518341) (specific version of VSCode, via an online machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it!

Install the `ms-python.python` VSIX from [the market place page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)'s "Download Extension" link. Then install it with `code --install-extension <path to VSIX>`.

When I do that with a network connection, for some reason it installs the Python and Pylance extensions, but not the Jupyter extension (which is part of the Python extension pack*). I'm not sure why that happens, but that's what happens for me. Maybe worth a bug report.

When I do that with no network connection, it just installs the Python package without installing any other extensions that are part of its extension pack. No error messages in the console. I found that surprising. Maybe worth a bug report.

You can look at the contents of the VSIX yourself. It's just a ZIP file. Use whatever program you have that can unzip such files. When I compare the Python VSIX with the Jupyter VSIX, I don't see the contents of the Jupyter VSIX in the Python VSIX, nor do I see any nested VSIX files or zip files, which indicates to me that no- an extension pack's VSIX does not contain the contents of the packed extensions' VSIXes.

If you want to install an extension pack without a network connection, you need to also manually grab the VSIXes for the extensions that are part of the extension pack.

---

* for context, this test and statement was made pretty much right before the April release (releases come out at the end of the release month) where Jupyter was changed to no longer be installed with the Python extension by default: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78#_jupyter-extension-no-longer-installed-by-default.

Comment: this was very thorough and helpful. thank you!